# Examples of Markov chains from real life

Tags: examples-counterexamples, markov-chains

I'm teaching a class with a very gentle introduction to Markov chains (the class is an alternative to taking calculus). I'm not a probabilist, so I haven't spent any time thinking about these objects. Does anyone know of any very compelling non-mathematical examples of Markov chains, or, at least, of non-mathematical things that can be well approximated by Markov chains?

Comment: So there's a lot of applications of SDEs, which can be approximated by Markov chains (through essentially random walks). There are also applications of birth-death processes to queuing problems. On a somewhat more mathematical front, Markov Chain Monte Carlo can be used to solve a wide variety of problems, some of which don't really have any underlying stochastic character.

Comment: I don't know what an SDE is. Would you be able to give sources where I can read a little more about your suggestion?

Comment: SDE is short for stochastic differential equation. These get used a lot in physics and finance.